# Login to ajax loading of home page

Tags: php, javascript, css, ajax, html

I am trying to create a dynamic login screen where my whole 'logged in' page isnt loaded into the dom until the form validates where the login screen scrolls down into the homepage without 'actually' scrolling.

I was thinking of doing this by

form -> ajax -> validate -> on validate ajax load expanding div under login area and load home page with ajax -> jquery hide login area.

Is there any easier way? if I already have both pages combined currently to just hide that part of the dom?

Answer (score 0):

In general, I'd propose to give [XAJAX](http://www.xajax-project.org/) a try.

The XAJAX library integrates well with PHP and e.g. allows to update several DOM elements at once.

In general, I'd prefer to run the login-operation in a non-AJAX fashion. But that's more or less a matter of taste. Once the user is logged in, I'd switch to AJAX.

Moreover, I wouldn't just hide the logged-in DOM element.

Comment: Yeah that's the way it is working at the moment, but it would be soo much more user friendly in my opinion, Im trying to make my site work without ever refreshing the user's page

Answer (score -1):

May be this could help you: **Login y logout con PHP, MySQL, JQuery y Ajax** (Spanish) http://bit.ly/tBmHtV

It have worked for me.

Comment: That isnt really what I meant, but thats a cool suggestion anyway